# Is it possible to run the same test class multiple times with slightly different properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I have a test class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = JaxRsClientTest.class, 
                webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,
                properties = {"server.port=9876", "accept=X", "content-type=Y"})
public class JaxRsClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeRest client;

//  A bunch of tests below

}
```

Bean `client` is a singleton proxy object and configured by using `accept` and `content-type` from `properties` field in `@SpringBootTest` annotation when context is initialized. It's interface `SomeRest` is just a bunch of business logic, so I can't manually configure low-level parameters such as `accept` and `content-type` headers (well, I actually can via reflection). I need to run this test class with 4 combinations of `accept` and `content-type`. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: There's parameterized Tests, see i.e. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm